# What does it mean when there are many defined classes and No of instances in Memory Analyzer(MAT)?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, jvm, eclipse-memory-analyzer

We have a spring boot project (programmed in groovy as well as Java) which is running on production environment. The program crashes from time to time, so we think there is memory leak issues. We made a dump and want to analyze it with MAT, we see there are a lot of defined classes and No of instances as show below, What does it mean when there are many defined classes and No of instances in Memory Analyzer(MAT)?

[image]

Comment: It means that the class is loaded but has no instances?

Comment: I suggest you to forget about anything you see regarding the `java.lang.invoke` package. The content is special and might confuse analyzing tools.

Comment: @PiRocks there are so many instances, 1612909!

Answer (score 1):

The `java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH` class is loaded 45 times.
Each time it was loaded by the system class loader (which is unusual - normally a class is only loaded once per loader, but the invoke classes are special), hence the 45 lines listing ''. The system class loader has itself loaded 3,725 classes, and there are a total of 1,612,909 instances of all those classes. That number of instances is nothing to do with the duplicate class, it just lets you know what the class loader is doing.